# Replace Android/Remix OS (Remix Mini PC) with Ubuntu via USB Boot

Tags: boot, unity, drivers, system-installation, android

I just bought a new [Remix Mini PC](http://www.jide.com/mini) that I had planned on hacking and installing Ubuntu 16.04 (or the whatever the latest **stable** version is). It works just like any other Android except it has two USB ports and connects via HDMI to a display (see above link). It doesn't have volume rockers to get to the recovery menu but it can still go to the recovery menu if you hold down F2 on boot. Due to the fact that it doesn't have a touch screen, I just want to install the normal PC version of Ubuntu from my bootable USB Flash drive. Does anyone know of a possible way to boot from the USB drive? If so, is there a specific way I need to install Ubuntu? Could I get extra drivers, and if so, how many might I need to get everything working (HDMI, Sound, Wifi, Bluetooth, ect.)? And lastly, if I had to install Ubuntu touch, could I still get the same apps and Unity like the desktop version? The system only has 16 gigabytes of space, so I'm still wondering if it would be worth it. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the Remix Mini is a awesome thing in itself ;)

Comment: Eh... Don't get it. It's not worth 90 bucks. After having for a year, I realized it was causing everything on my router to lose internet, not to mention it had horrible speeds. Now, I think I'm REALLY going to try putting Ubuntu on it, because it's a nightmare with their stupid OS.

Comment: oh okay! I thought it would be the ultimate product after trying their OS that they have made for PC. Couldn't get father due to my discrete graphics boiling the system :(

Comment: Oh no! yeah, it's not worth it at all; plus it goes REALLY slow, and it usually takes like 5 minutes to turn on, and then 60 seconds to even show the spotify splash screen... So yeah, don't buy, just get an android phone or something (Haha :))

Also, that sucks about your graphics card :(

Comment: @ComputerGuy Did you succeeded with the Ubuntu install? I also have a Remix Mini and I want to change to Ubuntu too.

Comment: @zkminusck Turns out you need a USB-serial converter to physically plug into the motherboard. I decided to stop trying, since I don't want to buy one, and I don't think the result would be worth it. In my opinion, the entire remix was a waste, as the Wifi card in mine ended up frying my router... 
Tl;dr: No. The remix just isn't worth it, with only 16 GB of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you cannot install Ubuntu Desktop because the processor is based on ARM architecture and Ubuntu Desktop is meant for x86 processors.

You should probably try to install the Ubuntu ARM version meant for Raspberry Pi. Please refer [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) wiki for the process.

Basically, it seems to give you the server edition and then you can install packages that give you the Desktop Environment. See the extract below from the wiki.

---

*This is a small ubuntu-server image. If you want a full desktop, go ahead and do so:*

```
$ sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop  # or
$ sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop  # or
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop  # etc
```

*Ubuntu (Unity) and Ubuntu-GNOME just display a blank screen, presumably because they require 3D compositing. Kubuntu works but is slow unless you turn off desktop effects under System Settings. Xubuntu and Lubuntu work fine out of the box.*